# Solving DateAdd Runtime errors in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to resolve the issue of using `DateAdd` in excel VBA. I am getting a `Runtime Error 6 Overflow` (most often) or a `Runtime Error 11 Division by Zero`. I have marked in the code where the runtime error always occurs. I have tried changing the variable types but not sure what the issue is. The dates that I read from the excel sheet are in the `Date` format (mm/dd/yy). Any suggestions on why I am getting the error at that line?

```
Sub date_diff()
    Dim todDate As Date
    Dim dt
    Dim diff As Long
    Dim dates(0 To 9) As Date
    Dim i As Long
    todDate = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Investing - Overview").Range("B6").Value
' dt is the Date of last signaling
    dt = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Investing - Overview").Range("B5").Value
    diff = DateDiff("d", dt, todDate)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim dtCell As Range
    Dim currDt As Date
    If diff < 32 Then
        MsgBox "Wait " & (32 - diff) & " days"
    Else
        For i = 1 To 10
            currDt = DateAdd("d", 20, todDate) -> RUNTIME ERROR HERE
            Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("US Stocks").Range("A5").End(xlDown)
            dates(i) = currDt
            MsgBox i
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd check your data and the format they are in, this worked for me just fine.  Make sure they are the same.

Comment: Likely unrelated, but why is `dt` declared as an implicit `Variant`? If it should be a date, make it a `Date`.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `currDt = DateAdd("d", 20, todDate)` with `currDt = 20 + todDate` ? (It might help identify the issue)

Comment: Run your script to that line, then hover over the parts to see if the error is in your todDate or DateAdd. Otherwise I built it on my PC and have no issues.

Comment: I have just checked by using `MsgBox TypeName(currDt) MsgBox TypeName(todDate)` and they are both indeed of the same data type. Also, doing `currDt = 20 + todDate` yielded `Runtime error: 11 Division by zero`

Comment: Check the value in `todDate`. It's a hunch but I don't think it contains a datetype value. Perhaps it's text that contains/ looks like a date?